# Algorithm for finding the outer layer of inner matrix inside a matrix

Tags: java, algorithm, loops, matrix

I am trying to solve the following algorithm, and I got stuck. I hope you could help.

By given:

1. Main matrix in size of N*N
2. Inner matrix in size of K*L
       (The inner matrix is contained in the main matrix, the indexes are given).

I should write a function that returns a list of all the elements in the outer layer of the inner matrix. If there are no elements, return an empty list.

In each iteration, the size of the inner matrix is getting bigger and includes the previous inner matrix + the outer layer.

**For example:**

By given the black main matrix and the red inner matrix, return the elements marked in yellow. continue until returned an empty list.

[image]

**Where I got stuck**

I can easily find the elements of the outer layer by increasing the range +1 of the inner matrix and comparing the edges of the main & inner matrix.
However, I got stuck how to increment the loop generally (increment the layers).
By the way, I am trying to avoid a recursive solution.

Comment: Do you have to return the elements in any special order?  Can the outer ring of elements be more than one row or column "thick"?

Comment: @markspack
(1) Do you have to return the elements in any special order?
 - No. I chose to implement it by using an ArrayList, but the order doesn't matter.

(2) Can the outer ring of elements be more than one row or column "thick"?"
- No. The Outer layer would increase in each iteration only in "one thick"

Comment: Sorry I don't understand when you say *increment the loop generally*. Get the new (K+1)x(L+1) matrix?

Comment: I don't understand example ("iteration") #2: you have a 4x4 outer matrix and apparently an 3x3 inner matrix.  How do you know to put the 3x3 inner matrix so that it includes the first column?  Why not place it so that the last column of the outer matrix is part of the 3x3 matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly, you can simply keep track of the coordinates of the top-left an bottom-right corners of your inner matrix, (y1, x1) and (y2, x2) respectively. You can then easily get the outer layer and expand the inner matrix as follows:

Get the outer layer : The coordinates of these elements are

- (y1-1, j) for j in max(0, x1-1),...,min(N-1, x2+1) (the top row, if y1 > 0)
- (y2+1, j) for j in max(0, x1-1),...,min(N-1, x2+1) (the bottom row, if y2 < N-1)
- (i, x1-1) for i in y1,...,y2 (the left column, if x1 > 0)
- (i, x2+1) for i in y1,...,y2 (the right column, if x2 < N-1)

Expand the inner matrix : You simply need to update the corner coordinates

- y1 = max(0, y1-1),  x1 = max(0, x1-1)
- y2 = min(N-1, y2+1),  x2 = min(N-1, x2+1)

Then repeat, until (y1, x1) == (0, 0) and (y2, x2) == (N-1, N-1)